# H2 logging Whitelabel error page. Using MySQL as prod and H2 as dev

Tags: spring-boot

I'm getting a Whitelabel error page

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
> Forbidden.

This is my H2 application.properties

```
##H2 CONSOLE - DEVELOPMENT

spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reusablerocket

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234

spring.jpa.database=h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

This is my  MySQL application.properties

```
##MYSQL DATABASE - PRODUCTION

spring.jpa.database=mysql

spring.datasource.url=mysql://localhost:3306/reusablerocket
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
```

this is my SecurityConfig code:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        userDetailsManager.createUser(User.withUsername("pablocarmona1@hotmail.com")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("1234"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build());
        return userDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/secure/**").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider(userDetailsService()));

        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

and I made the sql application.properties as my profile (I'm using eclipse)

I tried changing some settings, took out some dependencies, changed the username and password from the application properties. But nothing worked.

Comment: Please always include the complete error message

Comment: 403 forbidden is a http error message, not a database one. You need to provide a lot more context and debugging info for us to help.